# Unable to start Phantomjs driver from java .app on OSX

Tags: java, macos, selenium, jar, phantomjs

I have created an application on Java that starts a phantomjs driver.

My program successfully creates the phantomjs driver when launched from eclipse with the following lines:

```
DesiredCapabilities desireCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
desireCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, directory + "/phantomjs");
desireCaps.setCapability("phantomjs.cli.args", Collections.singletonList("--ignore-ssl-errors=true"));
desireCaps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0");
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desireCaps);
```

I created an .app as such:

[image]

where "MainJar.jar" is the jar generated by eclipse,
"launcher" is the batch that basically does `java -jar MainJar.app`, and "phantomjs" is the selenium phantomjs official executable.

When I launch the application from the ".app", I get the following error on `driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desireCaps);`:

> Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'Air-de-Me', ip: 'XXX.XXX.X.XX', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
>   Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver

However, when I run the application by launching the "launcher" script, the application successfully creates the driver. My first though was that the "app" could not find the phantomjs driver because the path was set incorrectly, but I printed `(phantomjs_file).exists();` in my log and it finds it correctly.

I have set rights on every single file inside my app and the app itself with chmod 777, just to exclude permission errors.

Is there a reason why the browser could not init?

Any help would be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my problem. The problem was that phantomjs could not get the permissions to write its own log file when run from the ".app".

I have found a way (the only way that worked for me), to disable phantomjs log-writting:

```
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder()
        .usingPhantomJSExecutable(new File("PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE"))
        .withLogFile(null).build(), 
        desireCaps);
```